# How can I format an array?

Tags: javascript, node.js

So, let's say I have an array of months. I want it to say what the item position is and the item name, and create a sort or list instead of having it be "january,febuary,march,april". Example below

```
``ITEM_POSITION`` - MONTH_NAME
``0`` - January
``1`` - Feburary
``2`` - March
``3`` - April

and so on...
```

How would I list the months like this?

(The Back Quote is intentional) (Sorry for bad explanation)

Comment: Put it in an array  and you are done. index->month.  First link google came up with: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you familiar with `for` loops? How about something like the following:

```
const months = ["january", "february", "march", "april"];
// print your header here
// ...
for (let idx = 0; idx < months.length; idx++) {
  // print desired info for each month here
  // this isn't the exact format you want, but here's a hint
  console.log(idx + " - " + months[idx]);
}
// print any "footer" here
// ...
```

This is not the only way to achieve what you want, but is probably the most straightforward.

Comment: I want to be able to collect that as one whole variable and not separate things.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, that should be achievable by creating another variable and appending to it in the loop. E.g. `let monthMsg = ''` at the top, then `monthMsg += <format you want>` inside the loop instead of `console.log`

Comment: So I tried ```monthMsg += idx + " - " + months[idx]```, and it would just give me ```0 - january1 - february2 - march3 - april``` Any ideas?

Comment: NVM XD, it was just that it was bunched together. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can store months in an array. Each element has its own index according to its position. Another way is to create an object and asign key/value pairs.

```js
//ARRAY
let arr = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April'];

//Access each arr element
arr[0];  // 'January'
arr[1];  // 'February'

//Iterate arr elements
arr.map(x => console.log(x));   // map method (iterates each element) and logs in console

//Sort
console.log(arr.sort());        // sort alphabetically


//OBJECT
let obj = {0: 'January',
           1: 'February',
           2: 'March',
           3: 'April'
           };

console.log(obj);

//Access obj properties
obj[0];     // 'January';
obj[1];     // 'February'
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're trying to create an object like structure.

like:

```
{ item_position: 0, month: 'January' }
```

you can do it like this (Even though is really redundant):

```
const months = ['january', 'february', 'march'];
const months_list = [];

months.forEach((month, index) => {
     months_list.push(
         {
             "ITEM_POSITION" : index,
             "MONTH_NAME" : month
         }
     )
})

months_list.forEach(item => {
     console.log(item.ITEM_POSITION, item.MONTH_NAME) // 0, 'january'
})
```